# Manhwa where female lead has red eyes, blonde hair, and divine powers

Tags: story-identification, manga

So there is this duke/emperor (I don't know). He can’t sleep, so he kidnaps the saint to help him sleep. Meanwhile, the maid (female lead) has holy powers, so she also helps him sleep. He ends up falling in love with her.

Answer (score 2):

Is this ***[Love Quest for a Servant Girl](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/love-quest-for-a-servant-girl)***...?

> To pass the time before surgery, Hwayoon read a romantic novel for some steamy scenes. Little did she know this would lead to her reincarnating into the story as an insignificant maid that's executed soon after. The goal is to survive, but things get out of hand... and steamy.
>
> [image: Promotional art for "Love Quest for a Servant Girl."]

A Korean woman is reincarnated within the world of a romance novel she'd read as Nina Cage, a blonde-haired, red-eyed girl who was raised in a Catholic orphanage.

The heroine of the novel is Serapi, a saintess with divine healing powers.

The male lead of the novel is the King of Iberia, who keeps the saintess a prisoner in his palace, since he needs her to ease his chronic pain so that he can sleep at night.

Nina also has divine powers, though not at the same level as the saintess, and is sold to the King to serve as a food taster and maid for the saintess.

The King takes a liking to her and has her sleeping beside him in his bed (clothed), along with the saintess. He needs to be in physical contact with the saintess for her power to work on him.

You can read the full manhwa at [Pocket Comics](https://www.pocketcomics.com/comic/163).